# SEO duplicate content

Tags: seo, search-engines, duplicate-content

I have a blog about a game. Lets say that the game releases some news and gives it to *Blog A* and *Blog B*.

Now my blog (*Blog A*) will copy that news and paste it in an article.

Somebody else's blog (*Blog B*) will now also copy that news and paste it in an article.

Would this result in a duplicate content penalty between *Blog A* and *Blog B*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blog B will have the duplicate content issues as Blog A was the first to publish it.

Comment: Ahh thank you, however lets say one thousand blogs post the same thing. Would the blogs that post after Blog A have the duplicate content issues?

Comment: It's hard to say exactly who gets the credit but the sites Google consider to be more authoritative will likely be ok with the other sites having duplicate content issues. That's why republishing press releases is useless as a method for generating content.

Comment: What a great answer, thank you! So instead of copying what press release/news directly says, would it be safe to re-phrase it?

Comment: Maybe. If you're looking for content but don't want to hurt SEO either use a canonical URL to the original press release or just block those pages from the search engine crawlers.

Comment: @GKhan14 - Yes, give it your own spin. I have a news site too and that is exactly what I do with incoming press releases. Look at Gizmodo too, they always have their own take on the news and below there is a button that says *Show Full Press Release*.

Comment: Rephrasing it isn't enough. You have to provide your own commentary  and point of view.  You can certainly publish quotes from it, but most of the content should be your own perspective about why it is relevant for your users.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thank you. My last question is, what if my blog and 10-15 other blogs have a page about a game. All of our articles are different, but they just surround the same topic. However, within that article there is a table, and all of the tables on all of the pages from the 10-15 blogs are the same. Would this be bad for SEO/would you recommend that I should remove the table on my page?